# Como não permitir o usuário acessar a página anterior de login/registro após fazer login ou registrar-se

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação ASP.NET e quando o usuário faz login e clica no botão do navegador para voltar ele consegue acessar a página de login/registro, mesmo eu fazendo a verificação da key do usuário logado na session.
Segue os prints:
1 - Fiz login
[image: Eu faço login]

2 - Estou logado, o site me redireciona para o index e eu clico no botão voltar.
[image: Index e clico em voltar]

3 - Após isso eu volto para a tela de registro/login o que não pode acontecer:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois da foto 3, se eu volto para o index, eu fico logado normalmente, para prevenir isso eu fiz uma verificação no controller verificando se o usuario está logado ou não, se sim ele volta para o index, porém quando o usuario clica em voltar parece que o navegador que faz esse controle. Já vi sites que não permite voltar na tela de login, alguém sabe como resolver isso? Segue a verificação no controller:

```
    public ActionResult LoginRegister()
    {
        if (Session["UserStatus"] != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoginRegister(string fr,string t,string ReT)
    {
        if (Session["UserStatus"] != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        //Validação e outros processos.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta acrescentar no construtor da página de login para não armazenar cache, acredito que isto resolva seu problema.

> Para .net 4x.

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public ActionResult LoginRegister()
    {
        if (Session["UserStatus"] != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View();

    }
```

> Para .net core use:

```
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
 public ActionResult LoginRegister()
        {
            if (Session["UserStatus"] != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use o ActionFilterAttribute**

Primeiro crie uma classe LoginFiltro(por exemplo):

```
public class LoginFiltro : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        object usuarioLogado = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Nome"];

        if (usuarioLogado == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                      new RouteValueDictionary(
                          new { action = "Index", controller = "Login" }));
        }
    }
}
```

que verifica se o usuário esta logado ou não. Senão estiver ele sera redirecionado para o Controller Login.

**No Controller**

Depois "decore" os controllers que deseja ter este controle de login com:

```
[LoginFiltro]
```

que ficara encima do nome do Controller.

Comment: Cassio vou aplicar sua solução em breve retorno com o resultado, VLW