# Forçar a atualização de um elemento em HTML/Javascript/ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-update, cache

No site que estou trabalhando, o usuário tem acesso a um editor de texto para mudar as labels em determinadas fotos. Ao editar o texto e dar "submit" nas respostas, os textos não atualizam nas páginas - O mesmo acontecia com as imagens do site, mas uma solução foi encontrada, colocando um número aleatório no final de todas elas, mantendo a unicidade.

As fotos a seguir demonstram o que quero dizer:

[image: Imagem a ser atualizada]

A imagem acima possui uma label (Polícia Militar, Navegantes).

Abaixo, o usuário tem a possibilidade de mudar tanto a imagem quanto o texto exibido ao lado dela:

[image: Foto 2, editor de texto]

Os valores não são atualizados. O mesmo acontecia com as imagens, mas como foi dito, um identificador aleatório foi "colado" no nome dela para o servidor (Azure) não confundir.

O que pode estar acontecendo?
(Estou usando cshtml/aspnet com mvc5!)

Já busquei diversas alternativas (tanto em inglês quanto em português) - a maioria delas informa sobre tags meta que incluem as opções "no-cache", "no-store", entre outras, mas nenhuma parece funcionar.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações e agradecimentos pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Talvez não seja a View e sim o método que você usa para trazer o conteúdo do banco de dados. Caso esteja usando EF para fazer a consulta no BD, tente fazê-la através de uma query em string (ex: "SELECT (campos) FROM dbo.Tabela") e executar com Database.SqlQuery(QUERY).ToList()

Isso faz com que os dados realmente sejam trazidos do banco, forçando a atualização.

Att.

Comment: Melhorei minha antiga solução com isso. Obg!!!

Answer (score 1):

Na assinatura de cada `Action` que você não deseja cachear coloque a seguinte anotação: `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]` no exemplo a seguir eu tinha problema com cache e resolvi dessa maneira.

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public ActionResult LoginRegister()
{
}
```

Fonte(minha própria pergunta, é um propósito diferente, mas a solução é a mesma): [Como não permitir o usuário acessar a página anterior de login/registro após fazer login ou registrar-se](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214129/como-n%c3%a3o-permitir-o-usu%c3%a1rio-acessar-a-p%c3%a1gina-anterior-de-login-registro-ap%c3%b3s-faz)

Caso não resolva comenta que encontraremos outra solução.

Comment: Infelizmente estas garantias já estão! Temo que o problema possa ser no get do servidor, já que abrir a página em modo privado também não recupera as informações corretas.

Ainda assim agradeço a resposta, Leo!

Comment: De onde você recebe as informações das imagens? via banco de dados?

Comment: @Momentanius ^^^

Comment: Isso! Estou usando SQL com os servidores da Azure!

Comment: Tem certeza que as alterações estão sendo feitas no banco?

Comment: @Momentanius, é só digitar @ colado com meu nome

Comment: Sim! A cada atualização, vou no banco e faço um refresh no mesmo. Os dados são enviados para lá, mas não estão sendo exibidos corretamente na view.

Quando eu rebuildo o projeto inteiro ele dá atualiza, mas antes disso, não.

Comment: Teria como você postar o código que você utiliza para popular a view?

Comment: o código do controller e a view em sí ?